# Access HCI bluetooth log from Samsung s8

Tags: logging

I have enabled the developer setting "Enable Bluetooth HCI snoop log", toggled the Bluetooth setting and restarted the phone. I have not being able to find the log files anywhere and was wondering how to access them.

Comment: Usually it should be created here: `/sdcard/btsnoop_hci.log`.